# How to correctly consume a produced Web Service? (Apache CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have created a SOAP WS and deployed it on a localhost. On the same server, I want to create a Web App which sends XML requests to the web service and consequently manipulates data in the DB.

Do I have to regenerate all the necessary java classes (wsimport) to use the web service, or is there any other way doing this? The generated classes mess up my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL, QName, and Service.

Let's say you have a service endpoint interface as follows :

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

    public interface HelloWorld{

        @WebMethod 
        String getString(String name);

    }
```

And a service endpoint implementation as follows :

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.bot.ws.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    @Override
    public String getString(String name) {
        return "Hello World received input = " + name;
    }

}
```

You can call this web service as follows :

```
public class WSClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ws/hello?wsdl");

        QName qname = new QName("http://bot.ws/", "HelloWorldImplService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);

        System.out.println(hello.getString("bot"));

    }

}
```

Keep in mind that you need to copy your web service enpoint interface to the web app that will call your web service if they are not in the same war. Also, this example assumes that your web service takes a String parameter and returns a String. If you are using user defined types, you need to generate classes from a schema using JAXB/XMLBeans etc.